# Angular-meteor Properly load relationships

Tags: angularjs, meteor, relationship, angular-meteor

I am trying to create a relationship between 2 collections on Angular-meteor.

```
areas - top in the structure
city - belongs to an area
```

On this [post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/), it uses Iron Router to join fields before the loading of the controller. It seems a nice solution since it will not bring more than once the area, if 2 cities belongs to the same area. **How can I do the mapping between both of them using angular's router?**

I've tried [publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) but it seems that for each city it will run a query for its area.

**Is there a more Angularish way of doing it?**

Answer (score 2):

Well

what I did was:

- created a publish with both the cities and areas. Areas are filtered only with the cities' areas
- on my controller, I have subscribed to this publisher and got both collections
- created a filter for printing the information on screen that will match the area id in city with the proper area id on my areas array, returning its name.

the code is something like:

```
// server side
Meteor.publish('citiesAndAreas', function(args) {
var cities = Cities.find({}, args);

// then extract those areas ids
var areaIds = cities.map(function(p) { return p.area_id });

// then return an array containing both the cities, and their corresponding areas
    return [
        cities,
        Areas.find({_id: {$in: areaIds}})
    ];
});

//client controller
$scope.modelItems = $meteor.collection(Cities).subscribe('citiesAndAreas');
$scope.areas = $meteor.collection(Areas);

// filter
angular.module("XXXX").filter('areaCity', function () {
    return function (area, city) {
        if (!city)
            return '';
        var name =  _.findWhere(area, {_id: city.area_id});
        if (name) {
            return name.title;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
});

// on the html
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in modelItems">
                {{item.title}}<br/>
                {{areas | areaProfession:item}}
                <md-button ng-click="remove(item)" aria-label="remove"><md-icon md-svg-icon="content:ic_clear_24px"></md-icon></md-button>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: If anybody ever needs it, I ended up implementing Adriano's solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32383930/1435476