# Handling relationships in meteor-angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

coming from a heavy `MySQL` and `PHP` background I can't really get my head over this.

I have a collection of `branches` with a ManyToOne relation to `Restaurants` (so there are many branches attached to the same restaurant).

Such relation is defined by the field `restaurantId`, which stores the id of the object. My `branches` collection appears as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "uH4KbNYxw8cnCEqvk",
    "address" : "1 High Street",
    "loc" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            0.0, 
            0.0
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "restaurantId" : "dvxZ2NiA3gbevffsk"
}
```

And of course the `restaurants` collection

```
{
    "_id" : "dvxZ2NiA3gbevffsk",
    "name" : "Restaurant name"
}
```

Now, I'm querying all the branches ordered by proximity using `$near`, and I can't find a clean way to get the name of the parent restaurants while looping over the branches.

Here is what I did - I mean, it works as it is, but I think performance-wise it has a lot to be improved

```
// controller
angular.module("MyApp").controller("SearchRestaurantsCtrl",
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){

        $meteor.subscribe('branches');
        $meteor.subscribe('restaurants');

        $scope.branches = $meteor.collection(function() {
            return Branches.find({
                loc: {
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [ $stateParams.lng, $stateParams.lat]
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 300000
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $scope.getRestaurant = function(restaurantId) {
            return Restaurants.findOne({
                _id: restaurantId
            });
        };
    }
);

// view
<div ng-repeat="branch in branches">
    <h3>{{getRestaurant(branch.restaurantId).name}}</h3>
    <address>{{branch.address}}</address>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using passing both the collection and filtering using angular:

Controller

```
angular.module("sushisushi24").controller("SearchRestaurantsCtrl",
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){

        $scope.branches = $meteor.collection(Branches).subscribe('branchesAndRestaurants');
        $scope.restaurants = $meteor.collection(Restaurants);
    }
);
```

Meteor Publish

```
Meteor.publish('branchesAndRestaurants', function(opts) {

    branches = Branches.find();
    restaurantIds = branches.map(function(branch) { return branch.restaurantId });

    return [
        branches,
        Restaurants.find({_id: {$in: restaurantIds}})
    ];
});
```

View

```
<div ng-repeat="branch in branches">
    <div ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants | filter: {_id:branch.restaurantId}">
        <h3>{{restaurant.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <address>{{branch.address}}</address>
</div>
```